# How to create custom input component with validation using angular material inputin Angular14?

Tags: angular, validation, input, angular-material

I want to create custom component for input text using angular material input but I don't know how can I bind validation of each input field to custom component. Is there any way to set errors of each field as array of objects like below

```
<app-custom-input
          formControlName="username"
          label="Username"
        ]"
        ></app-custom-input>
```

I want the validation to be set into formControl into my formGroup similar to this

```
 form: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
```

[https://stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-components-demo-acergn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fceva%2Fcustom-input.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fceva%2Fcustom-input.component.scss,src%2Fapp%2Fceva%2Fcustom-input.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write a component which implements the `ControlValueAccessor` interface.

Inside it, you will have a "standard" AbstractControl (i.e. `FormGroup`, `FormControl`, `FormArray`) instantiated like a normal one (i.e. `control = this.fb.control(null, Validators.required);`)

[Here](https://medium.com/ngconf/custom-form-inputs-with-controlvalueaccessor-4bd4eb6f8c22) you can find a good starting point.